# How to change the color scheme of PDF, from black background to white, for printing

Tags: pdf, printing, colors, rgb

PDF is in "night mode" black background with white text, making printing very inefficient.
Is there an efficient way to invert the RGB color scheme of the PDF while printing?

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Acrobat Reader, right-click on the document and select Edit > Preferences > Accessibility > Replace Document Colors > Custom Color. In the print settings, select Advanced Settings > Output > Color > Composite Gray > Negate.

Answer (score 0):

This Question may require several answers since there are many ways a PDF may have been inverted. Most common of all is that since PDF needs an added black background the majority of online converters simply print source pages as if negatives.

[image]

Thus in this case it is easy to do exactly the same and reprint the opposite way round.

If it was done as searchable text on black field it may require more specific, editing since simply reversing background will produce white on white

[image]

Or worse Acrobat Reader re-convert colours may convert letters into grey objects

[image]

One application worth  trying is Artifex MuTool which has an `-I`nvert colors option
[https://mupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutool-draw.html#:~:text=%2DI,Invert%20colors](https://mupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutool-draw.html#:%7E:text=%2DI,Invert%20colors).